# Código-Postal em c#

Tags: c#, código-postal

Alguém sabe como obter todos os códigos-postais de Portugal para usar num programa em c#?
Já tentei procurar mas não encontro nada concreto, por isso há alguém que me consiga ajudar?
Obrigado

Comment: Pelo que vi na net, os CTT já disponibilizaram uma API com acesso, entretanto deixaram disponibilizar...

Comment: Tens aqui um `.txt` para pedir: https://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/open/postalCodeSearch/postalCodeSearch.jspx

Comment: [Criei a Wiki `codigo-postal`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/codigo-postal/info) em que podemos colocar essas informações. Se for necessário estruturar um sistema, posso fazer um GitHub. O que acham?

Answer (score 0):

Podes encontrar todos os códigos postais de Portugal no [sítio dos CTT](http://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/restricted/postalCodeSearch/postalCodeDownloadFiles.jspx).
Terás de te registar antes de poder sacar o ficheiro.

Comment: eu tenho em folhas de excell todos os dados relativos a codigos postais concelhos e distritos mas agora o que faço? podem-me orientar? (para um projecto em c#)